# WCF Concurrency & Multi Threaded Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, concurrency

I have a WCF that is used by a multi threaded client for processing the number of requests parallel. Somehow it starts sharing data of two different requests/threads; I have tried to change the `InstanceContextMode` and `ConcurrencyMode` as following:

- Default InstanceContextMode = PerSession ConcurrencyMode = Single
- InstanceContextMode = PerCall ConcurrencyMode = Single
- InstanceContextMode = PerCall ConcurrencyMode = Multiple

But there is no luck so far. There is no shared variables and functions which may cause of this concurrency issue. According to the MS documentation `PerCall` creates instance for each single call and it doesn't make any sense that how data is shared between instances when they have their own private memory stack.

Workflow:
There are three main components WCF, .Net Assembly 1 and .Net Assembly 2. There is a function named "Process" of WCF which takes a string parameter and returns the structured object based on the processing done through WCF. There is no instance variable in the WCF; everything in the function. This function does little processing on the string and convert it into the structured object then pass it to the function of Assembly 1 does some processing and then pass it to the function of Assembly 2 using the invoke method of reflection. This is the entire process which somehow mix the end result of two different concurrent calls.

I would be really thankful if anyone can help to figure this issue out.

Comment: we need to see more code. How can data be shared when there are no shared variables?

Comment: Publishing the entire code here is not possible but I can give you an idea about the workflow of the code and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have those requests to be performed in parallel, but not sequentially as you have them? I have no issues with that by adding `serviceThrottling`  in config file. My config looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TeleEcgService.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TeleEcgService.IService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="1" maxConcurrentInstances="100"/>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000">
          <!--
          <security mode="Transport">
          </security>
          -->
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

As you can see, I can have max 100 parallel requests. And I use default `InstanceContextMode` and `ConcurrencyMode`